# Problems Installing a New Font

Tags: windows-10, fonts

**I am attempting to install a new font.**

- I open the control panel, and I open the "Fonts" tab.
- I go to the file tab in Fonts.

What I see when I open the File tab

[image: What I see when I open the File tab:]

Every time I attempt to install a new font, I follow the instructions listed on every website I can find for Windows 10.

In the instructions, it always states that I must go to the option; "Install New Font", which is not appearing. It does not seem to be entirely functional on my computer. I use Windows 10. I have zero viruses.

Comment: What file type are the fonts? If they're compressed in a zip file, did you unzip the font files someplace before attempting to install?

Comment: a google suggests it's in XP not windows 7. And I suppose not in Win 10. The accepted answer has a good method to try.

Answer (score 1):

Unzip the file onto your desktop

Right Click and Select Install.

This will install the font for you, no need to be navigating through folders.

Comment: You can also type "Fonts" at the Start Menu and open the Control Panel option, then drag your .ttf or other font type into that window.